# AngularJS not displaying scope data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having issues with a dynamically placed template.

My HTML for index.html looks something like this:

```
<body data-ng-controller="MainController">
<data-ng-include id="outside" src="dynamicTemplate()"></data-ng-include>
</body>
```

The index.html page displays a template based on a certain condition.

Here is the code for my home.html, which is the default template for index.html.

```
<span data-ng-bind="message" data-ng-style="messageStyle"></span>
<form data-ng-controller="FormController" data-ng-submit="processForm()">
other form stuff goes here
</form>
```

My FormController looks something like this:

```
  app.controller("FormController", ['$scope', '$http', '$window', function($scope, $http, $window) {
    $scope.message = "";




    $scope.processForm = function() {
      $scope.message = "Processing form";
      $scope.messageStyle = {
        "color": "green"
      };
      // Ajax Logic to process form
      .success(function(data) {
        $scope.message = data.msg; /* Message never gets updated in the view */


      });

    };



  }]);
```

The issue here is that the `$scope.message` never displays any data in the `data-ng-bind="message"` after the FormController gets called. I think the issue lies with the scope not knowing which controller it belongs to. How can I fix this?

Comment: you got Main in the front and formController in the backend posted here

Comment: @Brett The FormController is nested in the MainController here.

Comment: something isn't quite right here.  are you nesting controllers and trying to access something from one `$scope` in the other controller? `$scope` isn't shared.

Comment: @Claies I'm trying to assign the `$scope` of `data-ng-bind="message"` to FormController, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: also, you seem to be using `$scope` primitives, which can be troublesome in the best situations, due to [JavaScript Prototype Inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs), but can be downright broken when nesting controllers.  most likely (and unfortunately unverifiable without a working example of your issue), you are hiding the property you want to set with the nested controller.

Comment: and you *say* that you want to set a property in `FormController`, but your HTML shows that property outside that scope.

Comment: angular scopes **always** know which controller they belong to, and you can't set a property of a scope from a different controller (at least not the way you appear to be trying to).

Comment: why don't you wrap the entire code for home.html in a `<div>` and move the `ng-controller` to that element instead of the `<form>` element?

Comment: @Claies Thanks, it appears that pulling the `ng-controller` out of the form element works.